# how to delete column didn`t repeat in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i have this sample data :-

```
===============
pageid||SiteID
===============
   61  ||   1 

   62  ||   1 

   63  ||   1

   62  ||   2
```

and

> this table refrence to other table for pages , pageid unique in other
>   table

i need to delete data from this table and the referencing table ....but if the record repeat with other site id i must not delete it , when i select with site id all pageid will delete ( i can delete all pageid but 62 i want keept it in page table )

Comment: you want to delete the pageid's which dont have multiple entries?

Comment: i need to delete all pageid where for ex.(siteid =1) ...but the page id store with site id 1 and 2 , then i must exclude it from my query ..

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM @Page_Site
WHERE siteID=@siteID
AND pageID not 
in(
    SELECT pageID 
    FROM @Page_Site p2
    WHERE p2.siteID!=@siteID
);
```

I'm not certain how you use your query, so I formatted it as a parametered query. Otherwise, you simply have to replace both instances of @siteID with a any given value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` clause to prevent delete of pageid used in different siteID

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'OTHERSITE'
    FROM yourtable T2
    WHERE T2.pageid = yourtable.pageid
    AND T2.siteID <> yourtable.siteID)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the way that SQL Server allows window functions with `delete` and `update`.  So, it is also possible to use these functions for this purpose:

```
with todelete as (
      select s.*, min(siteId) over (partition by pageid) as mins,
             max(siteId) over (partition by pageid) as maxs
      from sample s
     )
delete from todelete
    where mins = maxs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do that in 2 queries. First delete all the linking id's, secondly delete the pages itself

```
delete from pageSiteLinks
where pageid in (
    select pageid
    from pageSiteLinks
    group by pageid
    having count(SiteID) = 1
);

delete from pages
where pageid not in (
    select pageid
    from pageSiteLinks
);
```